How to resolve indirect cyclic dependency issue in Spring
I am working on a spring project and I have two different modules, framework and workFlow.
framework serves as a Framework Module which provides structure and framework and has main class that loads and runs xml configuration files of all the other modules.
And, workFlow provides configurations(XML and java based) and perform some actions using some classes in Module one as dependencies.
Given that workFlow has framework in its class path as it is using some reference libraries and dependencies.
Now, when I run my main class in framework module, it says java configuration files mentioned in xml of workFlow module could not be found.
Even simple import statement says workFlow could not be resolved to a type.
I added a dummy boot class in workFlow module and beans are getting created but, when I run main class in framework module then it fails to find java config file.
How to get around this?
I tried adding workFlow as a dependency in framework module but it doesn't work.
My WorkflowConfig.xml looks like this:
<context:annotation-config/>
<context:component-scan base-package="com.workflow.configurations"/>
<bean class="com.workflow.configurations.JavaConfig"/>

My JavaConfig class looks like:
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basecPakages="com.workflow.configurations")
JavaConfig{

// some properties

@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource(){

//creating the bean

}
}

My Main class in framework Module looks like:
public class Main{

public static void main(String[] args){

private AbstractApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(String[] {"classpath*:*Config.xml"});

After this it gives ClassNotFoundException for com.workflow.configurations.JavaConfig.

I'm not sure I can fully follow your explanation. Some code would help, ideally a [mcve].

Are you sure the workflow module is on the classpath when running the framework module?

No, framework module is in the classpath of workflow module. but I cannot find the reverse.

Well, when running the application that is using the framework module workflow should be on the classpath as well. Otherwise how do you expect the framework to be able to detect any workflow related configuration?

Yes, thats where I'm stuck. If I add workflow in classpath of framework, then I get cyclic dependency detected exception.
I have added workflow jar in framework POM, I thought that will resolve it.

You might want to share some details on the exception you get. To resolve cyclic dependencies there are a couple of options like splitting one module (e.g. framework) into an api and an impl so you effectively create a tree again (framework-impl and workflow have a unidirectional dependency on framework-api). If that's not possible you could try to switch from dependency injection to lookups in one direction.
